# add a loading image while waiting for a response from post

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a loading image or change the mouse cursor while waiting for a response from a post in jquery.

jquery

```
$.post(url,data,
    function(response){
    //add a loading cursor to indicate that it is waiting for a response?
    alert(response);
});
```

i need this because the response is taking too long to popup.

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the cursor just before the ajax call, and change back in the success handler :

```
$('body').css('cursor','wait');

$.post(url,data, function(response){
    $('body').css('cursor','default');
});
```

if you use $.ajax you have a few more options:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('body').css('cursor','wait');
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    // do something with data
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('error');
}).always(function() {
    $('body').css('cursor','default');
});
```

same logic applies to a loading image or whatever you decide to add ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using $.ajax().  You need to have your hidden loadingImage in the DOM defined.

```
        $.ajax({                                                                                                           
            type:'POST',                                                                                                   
            ...                                                                                                           
            beforeSend:function(){                                                                                         
                $('.loadingImg').show();                                                                                
            },                                                                                                             
            complete:function(){                                                                                           
                $('.loadingImg').hide();                                                                    
            },                                                                                                             
            ...                                                                                                                                                         
        });
```